# What does any = lambda v: v mean?

Tags: python, lambda

What does `any = lambda v: v` mean? It seems `v` is only `v` itself.

```
class Object(object):                   
    """Common base class supporting automatic kwargs->attributes handling,
    and cloning."""
    attrs = ()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        any = lambda v: v
        for name, type_ in self.attrs:  
            value = kwargs.get(name)    
            if value is not None:       
                setattr(self, name, (type_ or any)(value))
            else:                       
                try:                    
                    getattr(self, name) 
                except AttributeError:  
                    setattr(self, name, None)
```

Comment: It makes any() be a function.

Comment: This is a bad idea because it hides the built in `any` function.

Comment: it's in kombu src,maybe a bug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lambda v: v` creates an *identity function*, which just returns its argument unchanged. Assigning it to a local variable is equivalent to defining a local function like this:

```
def any(v):
    return v
```

It can be useful as a fallback for code that wants to call a function to do some processing on the argument, for the cases where the real function is not available, or the processing is undesired.

In the code you posted, `type_` can be logically false (most likely `None`), which means that it is not to be called, so it's replaced with an identity function. The author could also have used a more explicit `if` to skip the function call in that case, at the price of additional clutter in the loop.

BTW `any` is a bad name for a local variable because it shadows the [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) with the same name and a completely different meaning.

Comment: it's also unpythonic to bind a name to an anonymous function.  since `any` is not used elsewhere, i think they should have just put the lambda inline inside that first `setattr`

Comment: @wim Placing anonymous functions in local variables is often done in Python, especially with very short lambdas used more than once in a single function. The posted snippet is not unpythonic, even if I don't agree with all of the author's choices.

Comment: guido disagrees.  there is no advantage over simply using a `def:`

Comment: @wim The "x = lambda:..." pattern is not mentioned in PEP8, and it can be easily found in Python's stdlib, so Guido's opposition is doubtful. The advantage is that the assignment visibly creates a variable, which can be rebound later, or at the point of the assignment, while defining it with `def` would look like inadvertent shadowing. Another advantage is less waste of vertical space. Either way, I've never heard of assignment of lambdas being unpythonic, so a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Also note that putting the `lambda` inside the loop actually slows down the loop because a new function object needs to be created in each iteration. Placing the definition (be it by `lambda` or `def`) outside the loop makes sure the function object is shared.

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` means "create a function, dynamically". Its part of lambda calculus(Alonzo Church's papers) and the basis of Functional programming.

The expression `lambda v: v` creates a function that accepts a parameter(`v` in this case) and returns the parameter back

Comment: thx too,it is my mistake,i want to ask it do this,lambda v:v do nothing but only return arg itself,now i got the answer :）

Comment: `lambda` is not about creating dynamic functions—all functions are dynamic in Python—it's about *unnamed* functions. `lambda` allows one, for example, to pass the function object directly as argument to another function, something that is not possible with `def`. Since the quoted code immediately assigns the lambda to a variable, the author could have just used `def`. (The comments to my answer contain a mini-discussion about pythonicity of such an assignment.)